# jpql "join fetch" vs EntityGraph

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I want to load related entities by using either jpql or jpa entity graph.

It seems both do the same thing.

Why should I use **Entity Graphs** instead of plain **jpql**? Are there any benefits?

What is the difference of using jpql:

```
select distinct u from User u join fetch u.hobbies a join fetch a.tasks
```

or Entity Graph:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "User.eagerfetch", attributeNodes = { 
        @NamedAttributeNode("hobbies"),
        @NamedAttributeNode("tasks")})
```

Comment: In theory multiple levels of joins like you have here are not allowed in JPA, so presumably the correct way to do it only exists as EntityGraphs. Note that your EntityGraph appears incorrect in that to do two levels of joins like your query you need to have SubGraphs or something of the sort. I have a fairly significant project that had joins like you have and I converted it to EntityGraphs. I didn't see any difference in terms of the queries generated but it did remove the validation errors DevStudio was giving me. Presumably I have a "more correct" app but where that matters is not clear.

Comment: Yes, `@NamedEntityGraph`needs a `@NamedSubgraph` of tasks.

Comment: I think there is a limitation in @EntityGraph, where you can't perform a findAll entities and get the relationships of each entity without making a `where` like statement, example you can't do : `@EntityGraph` List<Model> findAll(); thus it should be `@EntityGraph List<Model> findAllBy(); ` or `@EntityGraph List<Model> findAllByIdNotNull(); `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Difference is level of professional maturity of the code.

Clarity and readability, maintainability and code quality is significantly better with NamedEntityGraphs.

EntityGraph are evaluated compile time and it is less error prone as it is tightly coupled with the Entity definition. Any changed to Entity class breaks the Graph definition so that code does not even compile with those mistakes unlike with query strings. Hand written queries are hack solution. Not to mention that all the entity definitions are on one place; in the @Entity class not all over the place.

Comment: *EntityGraph are evaluated compile time* how does that possible? Is there a compiler preprocessor which validates `@Entity` & `@EntityGraph`?